# Grouping routes with Flow Router in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, flow-router

In Flow Router, I have some routes

- /projects/project-name
- /projects/project-name/tasks
- /projects/project-name/tasks/deleted-tasks
- /projects/project-name/tasks/completed-tasks
- /projects/project-name/tasks/labels/school
- /projects/project-name/tasks/labels/football
- /projects/project-name/tasks/labels/training
- /projects/project-name/tasks/labels/personal
- [...]

So almost all of my routes should share most of the same characteristics.

Are there any tricks to group my routes, so I do now have to check if the project exists in every single route or if can I say that some routes build upon other routes, so I do not have to write the long paths for all the routes?

I have found Flow Router, but it doesn't seem that's right tool to accomplish what I need.

Comment: Hi @Jamgreen, please accept the answer if it helped in your problem. If not, maybe you can provide more details to improve the answer. Also, from your profile I noticed that you don't accept answers to a lot of your questions. I would request you to do the same for other questions as it will help other programmers with similar questions which is the essence of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flow router definitely has the ability to group your routes. You can group them as follows -

```
var projectRoutes = FlowRouter.group({
  prefix: '/projects/project-name',
  name: 'projects',
});
```

To handle routers within this group, you can add

```
// route for /projects/project-name
projectRoutes.route('/', {
  action: function() {
    BlazeLayout.render(...);
  }
});

// route for /projects/project-name/tasks
projectRoutes.route('/tasks', {
  action: function() {
    BlazeLayout.render(...);
  }
});
```

This is just an example for grouping your routes.

You can read more [here](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router#group-routes).